# Showing a preview of a youtube video when setting the link in comment php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to develop in my website a preview of youtube link like facebook.

For example: If i set in comment a link of youtube video like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TF00hJI78Y, a preview of this video will be showed in comment.

How can i do this??

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried solving this yourself? I'm sure there's a lot of stuff out there.

Comment: Thanks for help. The problem is that i don't know how to proceed and if there is a plugin to do this. If you can tell me how to do this  and i will try to do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the `link` or `url` with an `Iframe`

For you
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TF00hJI78Y`

you have to replace that text for -->

`<iframe width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7TF00hJI78Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Thanks for help. But how can i integrate this frame in a textarea and how can the preview of link video will be showed in the textarea

Answer (score -2):

<s>https://www.youtube.com/embed/7TF00hJI78Y?start=500&end=600
start en end video and with javascript you can turn off the music.
and then onclick you can remove the start en end from the embed and put the music on</s> method doesn't work anymore.